# node server crashing when validation error occurs with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created a dynamic schema for every user with node and mongoose as given below.

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    require('mongoose-currency').loadType(mongoose);
var Currency = mongoose.Types.Currency;

var values = 'Credit Debit'.split(' ');

var schema = new Schema({
        amount: {
            type: Currency,
            required: true
        },
        type: {
            type: String,
            enum: values
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    });

exports.create_database = function(mobile) {
    return mongoose.model('personal_'+mobile, schema, 'personal_'+mobile);
};
```

I have used this in a personal router code given below

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var database = require('../models/personal');
var Verify = require('./verify');

var personalRouter = express.Router();
personalRouter.use(bodyParser.json());
personalRouter.route('/')

.get(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function (req, res, next) {
    var mobile = req.decoded._doc.mobile;
    var Personal = database.create_database(mobile);
    Personal.find(req.query)
    .exec(function (err, personal) {
        if (err) next(err);
        res.json(personal);
    })
})

.post(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function(req, res, next) {
    var mobile = req.decoded._doc.mobile;
    var Personal = database.create_database(mobile);
    Personal.create(req.body, function(err, personal) {
        if(err) next(err);
        console.log('Personal Record added!');
        var type = personal.type;
        var amount = personal.amount/100;
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.end('Added the '+type+' record of amount = '+amount);
    })
})

module.exports = personalRouter;
```

Now everything works good withe the get and the post routers untill i pass in values which do not go with the mongoose schema.
Eg. If i pass in the value as say without a description my server will give a validation error and crash.
I tried replacing next(err) with throw(err in the code without any luck.
I want the error to be displayed and prevent the server from crashing and shutting down.
Please help me, where am i going wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find how to fix this?